# Проверять input поле на ввод чисел, если число начинается с 2, отображать одну картинку, если с 52 то другую картину

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Есть инпут

```
<input required type="text" maxlength="23" tabindex="2" class="silver ui_creditcard error validate" id="credit_card_number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Номер вашей карты'" value="" placeholder="Номер вашей карты" pattern="[0-9 ]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

как реализовать логику, что если первая цифра 2 отображать один логотип платежной системы если первые числа 52 то другой логотип?

знаю что нужно сделать лиснер: который будет смотреть на инпут, если первая цифра == 2 то добавить клас к инпуту и этому класу присвоить логотип и так далее) 
проблема в том что не могу описать это на js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  document.querySelector('.block').style.display = 'none';
  if (this.value.substr(0, 1) == 2)
    document.querySelector('.block1').style.display = 'block';
  else if (this.value.substr(0, 2) == 52)
    document.querySelector('.block2').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text">
<div class="block block1">
  картинка 1
</div>
<div class="block block2">
  картинка 2
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on("keyup", function() {
  $(".block").hide();
  if ($(this).val().substr(0, 1) == 2)
    $(".block1").show();
  else if ($(this).val().substr(0, 2) == 52)
    $(".block2").show();
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type="text">
<div class="block block1">
  картинка 1
</div>
<div class="block block2">
  картинка 2
</div>
```